# How to create perl script to reach many hosts and update or do custom jobs

Tags: mysql, git, perl, svn, ssh

So once a week or a month we do an update to many server machines.
Sometimes a Git pull is enough, some times an SVN update, sometimes there are changes to the database. Or a combination of those. Also there is this project that has many little servers that have a very simplified version of our system and very unreliable internet. Sometimes it might be done from one of the servers, sometimes from the local working computers.

I would like to do our work a bit easier by going through all our servers and doing the appropriate actions. I have found a couple of useful Perl packages: Net::SSH::Perl and Net::SSH::Expect;
The Net::SSH::Perl fails me.
Also I have not found out how to use its `cmd` command in succession. For example:

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
$ssh->login($user, $pass);

my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd('cd web/scripts && ls -la ');
warn Dumper $stdout;

my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd('ls -la');
warn Dumper $stdout;
```

The 2 `ls -la` commands return different results. As far as I can understand (and is explained in the documentation) the ssh executes the command and then exits. It is said that I could use SSH 2 version of the SSH protocol (or something like it) and should not have this problem, but it persists (or I don't understand how to use it).

Also if a password is asked of me (for example if I run `mysql -u user -p`) I am unable to provide it. I've tried it with the `$ssh->cmd($cmd, [ $stdin ])` , second option but to no result. The mysql is just an example. I might wish to add an IP to `/etc/hosts` and be prompted for `su` password or `svn update` a file and be asked for my SVN password. I know that most of those processes can be configured to not ask for passwords but we want them to ask for password.

The `$ssh->shell` option seems like would do the trick but when I do something like this:

```
$ssh->shell();`ls -la`;
```

the backslashed command doesn't go to the ssh-shell. Actually I have no idea where it goes or if does anything.

The Net::SSH::Expect fails me when there is a bad internet connection.

For MySQL purposes I have created a Perl script that makes connections with each different host and does the changes I want. But it would be great if I could make it all in one script.

I would be very grateful to gain some more understanding on this topic.

Comment: [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel)!

Answer (score 3):

This is what [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) is made for. It uses SSH to communicate to multiple hosts, and provides a decent variable scoping system and flow control for applying various tasks to various hosts.

You can build your own configuration management with perl, but ansible with `raw` commands (which don't require python on the remote system) or more full fledged modules (which do) is already implemented and takes the same approach.  Do yourself a favor- don't reinvent this wheel.

Ansible is far from perfect, but it covers your use case very well.

I personally run it from a docker container because python's package installation story is almost as bad as Perl's :P

Comment: Some other options: [Puppet](https://puppet.com/), and [Rex](https://www.rexify.org/) built in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

On a pure perl basis you also have Rex, see [rexify Web site](https://www.rexify.org)
Which is a kind of Ansible, it got ssh, parallel job and plenty of features but more perly.
OK, it's simpler than Ansible, but it worth a try.